# Number-guessing game in Kotlin

Tags: beginner, number-guessing-game, kotlin

I am a Java developer, and I recently gave Kotlin a try.
To begin, I did a little exercise I often do when I start a new language, to verify I got the very basics: the more or less game.
The code I submit there is working fine, but of course I suspect it may be too much like Java, and I would like you to point to me how I can make my code more Kotlin.

```
package fr.caro

import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val min = 0
    val max = 100
    var nbAttempts = 0
    val random = SplittableRandom()
    val reader = Scanner(System.`in`)
    val goal = random.nextInt(min, max)
    var userGuess: Int

    computerSays("I chose a number between $min and $max")
    do {
        nbAttempts++
        computerSays("What's your guess?")
        userGuess = reader.nextInt()
        if (userGuess > goal) computerSays("less !")
        else if (userGuess < goal) computerSays("more !")
    } while(userGuess != goal)

    computerSays("Congratulation ! You found in $nbAttempts attemps.")
}

fun computerSays(text: String) {
    println("Computer : " + text)
}
```

PS: I wonder if putting the min and max values in a Pair object would be a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## When statement

You could replace:

```
if (userGuess > goal) computerSays("less !")
else if (userGuess < goal) computerSays("more !")
```

and

```
computerSays("Congratulation ! You found in $nbAttempts attemps.")
```

with:

```
when {
    userGuess > goal -> computerSays("less !")
    userGuess < goal -> computerSays("more !")
    userGuess == goal -> computerSays("Congratulation ! You found in $nbAttempts attemps.")
}
```

### Extension functions

You could write computerSays as:

```
fun String.outputAsComputer() {
    println("Computer : " + this)
}
```

then to output `Computer: ABC` you could just write:

```
"ABC".outputAsComputer()
```

**Although there are good arguments for and against this, it is more a chance to get used to extension functions**

Comment: Thank you very much ! I made a new commit on this applying your tips and a friend's advice. If interested : https://github.com/CarolineChaudey/KotlinTraining/commit/e1ad204278b0e0a4b6df00d879bda2aaddfdb9e8